# SQL Joining Tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to to join two tables in order to replace the numeric values of one from the other, the problem is that i have two columns in the same table. See this example to make it clear :

Table_1 `t1_ID INT, t1_Name VARCHAR(20)`

Table2 `t2_ID INT , ONE Table_1 , TWO Table_1`

in table 2 i store the id and i want to make a join in order to replace these id's with t1_Names.

I have tried this structure but it gives wrong answers

```
    Select *
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.table1_id
    JOIN table3 t3_1 ON table2.table3_id_1=t3_1.id
    JOIN table3 t3_2 ON table2.table3_id_2=t3_2.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the same table twice, but you need to give this table different names (alias name)

```
Select t2.id, t1_1.name, t1_2.name
FROM table2 t2
JOIN table1 t1_1 ON t1_1.id = table2.table1_id
JOIN table1 t1_2 ON t1_2.id = table2.table2_id
```